# How do you run a "do" block in a Rails Model while still listing a :dependent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

So I have a User model that :has_many other models like Documents, Videos, Posts and the like. My question arises when I execute a "do" block from the User model like so:

```
has_many :posts do
    def recent
      find(:all, :order => 'created_at desc', :limit => 12)
    end
  end
```

This just lets me call something like user.posts.recent to find only those posts associated with the User. With this in place, how can I still add a :dependent => :destroy or :dependent => :delete_all to this association? Everything I have tried so far has errored out on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should take a look at using [named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108).

There's no reason why you should have a do block against your association.

You you should turn that recent method into a named scope and you can then tack on :dependent => destroy etc etc.

Good luck!

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a recent_ method for all the models I needed this with and then moving the :dependent part in. Now the association is just that + the dependent and then I have something like:

def recent_posts
self.posts.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 12
end

Answer (score -1):

This should work just fine AFAIK:

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy do
    def recent
      find(:all, :order => 'created_at desc', :limit => 12)
    end
  end
```